# Creating Trip Distribution Matrix QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

What is the easiest way to create a trip distribution matrix in QGIS? I've counted my pickup points in each polygon and drop-off points in each polygon but I can't seem to find a way to link them (as you do when making a trip distribution matrix).